# Rails mode accepts_nested_attributes_for working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have models like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :business
end
class Business < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many : locations
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:location].blank?} 
  atr_accessible :name, :locations_attributes
  ...
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :business
  ...
end
```

when I fill in the address in the form, and post form to the `create` action of BusinessesController, the log show that the parameters are correct:

```
... 
"business"=>{"name"=>"sos","locations_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"address"=>"location1"}, "1"=>{"address"=>"location2"}}}
...
```

In the `create` action of BusinessesController

```
# :Post /usres/1/businesses
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id]）
  @business = @user.build_business(params[:business])
  if @business.save 
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

I check the log and found that `@business.save` did not insert any information about the locaitons to the database, but only the information about business, but the `params[:business]` clearly contains the locations hash, so where I was wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess where it goes wrong is in the reject_if check,

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, 
   :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:location].blank?}
```

Where do you have location attribute in locations table? As i understand you should check in the following way

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, 
   :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:address].blank?}
```